# Router.current().route.getName() is returning an error server side

Tags: meteor, iron-router

`Router.current().route.getName()` is returning an error when I use it in a method call (server side method). I thought they say Iron-Router is supposed to work both client and server side. The error I get is

```
Error invoking Method 'mySeverSideMethod': Internal server error [500]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half way right, the router works on both client and server. However the server-side implementation is meant for server side routes (eg. REST endpoints). There is no "state" sharing between client/server with iron:router (when invoked inside methods), so `Router.current().route.getName()` is going to throw you this error, because `Router.current()` is undefined.

Comment: This is correct but it does not help with what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iron:router can create server side routes, but that api is client only

[From the docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#server-routing):

```
Router.route('/download/:file', function () {
  // NodeJS request object
  var request = this.request;

  // NodeJS  response object
  var response = this.response;

  this.response.end('file download content\n');
}, {where: 'server'});
```

You have access to the NodeJS request object so you should be able to find what you need there, e.g. `this.request.route`, `this.request.path`.

Comment: I'll try your answer and come back to you.

Comment: I only had time to read the docs and familiarizing myself now. This does not help me as this.request will have to be set on the client; and data set on the client can't be trusted. It would be great if this.request had something that is set automatically by the browser and can't be changed on the other end. Thanks anyway. It sucks that I can't find an easy way.

Comment: It would be nice as well if iron router could automatically set a value that could be used on the client and that value could not be tempered with on the client or along the way

Comment: How do you think the server decides which handler should respond to this request?  If those values were tampered with by a malicious client the server would not call this code.

Comment: I found it better to use the https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/ package rather than iron:router's server side routes.

Comment: This is what I meant to say:  
"I only had time to read the docs and familiarizing myself now. This does not help me as this.request will have to be set on the client; and data set on the client can't be trusted. It would be great if this.request had something that is set automatically by the browser and can't be changed on the other  'client'.

Comment: And: "It would be nice as well if iron router could automatically set a value that could be used on the 'server' and that value could not be tempered with on the client or along the way"

Answer (score 0):

When calling a Method, you're not going through a 'route' as defined by Iron-Router: it's a route defined by the Meteor framework. It does not care what route the client is on.

So, if you need to know from what page the client is calling the endpoint, you should pass it as a parameter to the Method.

```
Meteor.methods({
    "myEndPoint": function(route) {
        // use route here.
        return //something
    }
})
```

Comment: well, i don't know of another way to know what route you are on. A Method can be called from any route anyways, so maybe you should just not use a Method but put the things your need into a Collection that is only subscribed to in the route you target.